# how to dispatch an redux action when refreshing the page or directly enter the URL with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am using react-router to build a assets management app. The app should provide a dedicated asset editing page for every individual asset, so in my route component I have something like this:

```
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="Home" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/assets/:assetsID" component={assetsPage}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

When the user is on the home page, he can click on the assets to bring up the assets page. The click will also fire a async action to fetch the assets from the api and update the assets page.

The problem with this flow is that, when the user is already in a specific assets page and he clicks refresh, or he directly enters a specific assets URL. The action is not fired, and the page will not be populated by any data

How should I solve this problem ?

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/227

Comment: Where is fetch action called from now?

Comment: just dispatch your action in <assetsPage /> componentWillMount method